# QGIS equivalent to MapInfo Sum Attributes for selected vector objects?

Tags: qgis, vector, fields-attributes, statistics

I´m looking for QGIS equivalent to the basic MapInfo tool "Sum Attributes".  I´ll explain what it does:

For selected objects in a vector layer, a popup window shows basic statistics such as:
- Sum and Average for numerical fields
- count of selected objects
- calculated spatial information such as Area
The popup window stays on top and is dynamically updated every time the selection changes.

The great thing about this tool is that its simple and dynamic, activated by a single click of a button on the standard toolbar.

So far I haven´t found a QGIS equivalent for this.  QGIS ´Basic Statistics´ is similar but too clunky.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I see your questions are repetative. I guess the shift from ArcInfo to QGIS gives you a hard time, but most of your questions relate to GUI; and as far as I know in this case, and in your [former question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142266/qgis-howto-dynamic-spatial-join-select-tool-equivalent-to-mapinfo-boundary-sel), I belive the answer is no. The GUI is different. I might suggest that you either focus on functionality, or write your own GUI to satisfy your needs.

Comment: I see you didn´t properly read my post.  Do you have an answer to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a **Statistics Panel** (activate via View | Panels | Statistics Panel) that calculates all kinds of statistics:

[image]

Note the **Selected features only** checkbox at the bottom of the panel:

[image]

---

Previous answer:

The closest tool to what you describe is the Live Statistics plugin. It can be configured to compute different statistics

[image]

and shows the results in a status bar in the bottom left corner of the main window

[image]

Comment: I´ve now found LiveStats by checking the Experimental Plugins setting, and so far its the closest tool i´ve seen to the MapInfo functionality.  Can it be configured to automatically provide stats for all numerical fields within the [active] table? (ie without manually configuring for each field)

Comment: @Nataniel for follow up questions I think it is best to ask a new question unless Underdark is happy to expand upon her answer to your original question.

Comment: @Nataniel I don't think that's currently possible. Please upvote answers that help solve your problem.

Comment: Statistics Panel is excellent, thanks for your answer!